# Fancybox options don't apply

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I got this really basic code with options for Fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".publications a").fancybox({ 

        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 350,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'titlePosition' : 'over'
    });
});
```

And I got that html with content mostly from php (loop using while).

```
<div class="publications">
    <a title="My title" href="#data2">  Few text goes here </a> 

    <div style="display:none">
        <div id="data2">
            <h3>Abstract</h3>
            Some text goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <br/>
```

The inline default fancybox is working good but I can't manage to apply any options on it. I wish I could resize it and move the title but it just simply not happenning.

Any clue?

Comment: Does `div.publications` has a closing tag? Where is the above JS snippet located on your page? it should be located just before `</body>` and after inclusion of jquery and fancybox.

Comment: Yes div.publications is </div> after my div#data2. The script is the last thing just before </body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Fancybox2 from [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). If you are, you should look at their [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) on how to properly use their plugin. I see that your code differs form their API.

Also you should use Firebug for Mozilla Firefox (their console) or Chrome Developer Tools to see if you've made any JavaScript typos or mistakes.

Comment: You are so right. I was using fancybox.net docs instead of http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs